# problems on topology involving basis and sub-basis

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Need some help guys, The question was: Can you define a basis generated by a sub-basis?

I tried to prove this today in class. My prof said that everything is correct except B3 (the 3rd basis). I didn't declare or define it properly and without that I claimed that there exists a basis B3 which follows the definition or 2nd criteria of a basis. How should I define that in my proof?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explicitely define the element $B_3$. Here $B_3 := B_1 \cap B_2$ suffices. ,

Comment: How to do that? I got confused there. I was thinking of defining B3 as a set which contain only one element common in both B1 and B2. Will that work?

Comment: You need an $B_3$ to be a set in $B$ i.e. a finite intersection of $S_i$. The set you propose will in general not be of this form.

Comment: Ok got it, cool.

Comment: Please replace the picture of text by actual text to increase accessibility.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I use Latex for writing a paper where you need to write the proofs. Latex is good, but here I think it doesnt work. MathJax works and I dont know how to use that. Sorry!!

Comment: @G.Chiusole: got it now, if we let that or we say: "Let us suppose B3 := B1 intersection B2, then the remaining statement follows.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun the thing is that you want to show that such a set exists, and then you say “yes, there is one! B1 intersect B2. Let us call this set B3. Then B3 has the desired properties.”

Comment: Ok, got you. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun You can use $\LaTeX$ here just fine using MathJax. Have a look at the [tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did every thing correctly.

For the $B_3$ you looking for, note that elements of the basis $B$ are finite intersections  of subbasis $S$ and you reach to $B_2\cap B_2$ is in the basis $B$ because $B_1\cap B_2$ is a finite intersection of elements of $S$.

Now you looking for a $B_3$ such that $B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$? Take $B_3=B_1\cap B_2$.

Comment: Can i do that? I was thinking of doing that at some point of time, however I didnt coz I thought whether I will be able to assume that or not. So, can I do: "let us take"/"Suppose" ?? Let me know.

Comment: We can do it because the intersection is of the desired form. But it is not possible always. E.g. In the case of open disks of $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can't.

Comment: ok got it, I can use this counter example too. This will work.

Comment: Then, why you don't accept the answer?

Comment: Did that now...

Comment: Your kindness :)

Answer (score -1):

The base could also be written as:

$$\mathcal{B}=\{ \bigcap \mathcal{S}': \mathcal{S}' \subseteq \mathcal{S} \text{ finite }\}$$

with the convention (follows from void truth considerations) that $\bigcap \emptyset = X$, which then handles the first demand on candidate bases, that $\bigcup \mathcal{B}=X$. This way we don’t even have to ask for $\mathcal{S}$ to cover $X$, as some texts do, superfluously.

$\mathcal{B}$ is then by construction closed under finite (or dual) intersections, as the union of two (or finitely many) finite subfamilies of $\mathcal{S}$ is also finite, and this implies the second demand on bases (as e.g. Munkres defines them).

We can then just take $B_3= B_1 \cap B_2$ for all $x$ in that intersection. Maybe you should have made *that* fact more explicit.